# Remote Certificate invalid error Before ServerCertificateValidationCallback is called

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, x509certificate, soap-client, ws-security

I am getting an exception when attempting to connect to a SOAP 1.1 server.  I received the WSDLs from the other organization and used .net to bring that into my project as a Service Reference.

It is required that we use include a MTOM attachment and HTTP gzip compression.  It further requires Web Services Security (WS-Security) version 1.0 (using the OASIS standard) for end to end security using the X.509 authentication framework.

I am working in c# with the 4.5.2 .Net framework.

Here is the relevant sections of my app.config with potentially sensitive information redacted:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="customHttpBinding" allowCookies="true" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

[snip]

<client>
  <endpoint address="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customHttpBinding"
    contract="SERVICENAME.BulkRequestTransmitterPortType"
    name="BulkRequestTransmitterPort">
    <identity>
      <certificateReference storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"
        findValue="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

The Xs is the serial number of my key (confirmed to be in my computer's store) and the Y is the endpoint

Here is the section where I create and call the service (the Xs is the same certificate):

```
  var transmitter = new BulkRequestTransmitterPortTypeClient();

  transmitter.ClientCredentials?.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
      StoreLocation.CurrentUser, 
      StoreName.My, 
      X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, 
      "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

  var response = transmitter.BulkRequestTransmitter(
      securityHeader, 
      security, 
      ref businessHeader, 
      transmitterManifestReqDtl, 
      transmitterType);
```

It blows up on that last line with the following error:

```
ex  {"Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'YYYYYYYYYYYY'."}    System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException}
    +InnerException {"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."}    System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}
        +InnerException {"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."}    System.Exception {System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException}
```

Whenever I do a search I found two suggestions, The first was to ensure that the server certificate is in my trusted store and the third party authority was trusted.  I have verified that both are in my local computer's store and are trusted.  The second and most common suggestion was to override ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback with return true like this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
};
```

As hesitant as I was to try this (I don't like using bad practices even in development environments) I figured the use in debugging would be worth it.  Sadly the breakpoint *never hits*.  I get the error **before** the ServerCertificateValidationCallback fires off.

I am now at a loss.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong as every change I make to the configuration creates an error at a much earlier point so I think I'm on the right path, but am not sure why the validation process is failing and how to resolve it.  I would appreciate any assistance that can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the server in question not using certificates.  If you inform .net to expect one from the server, it fails with this error message before getting to the ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, I'm not a telepath and can tell what exactly is causing your issue. However, I can provide some insights.

for debugging purposes only, you can get exact reason why the connection fails. Use this callback delegate:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
};
```

and set a breakpoint on delegate call. When fired, use your debugger to examine `chain` parameter. There is `ChainElements` property that holds a collection of [X509ChainElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainelement(v=vs.110).aspx) objects. Each object is associated with a particular certificate in the chain and status of each certificate in the chain and certificate status (via [ChainElementStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainelement.chainelementstatus(v=vs.110).aspx)). Note that chain elements statuses are cumulative, this means that errors are propagated down from the most top certificate. In other words, `ChainElementStatus` member will contain errors associated with the particular `ChainElement` plus combined errors from upper levels.

Once the issue is identified and resolved, remove this delegate.

Another option is to pass remote server's certificate file (only public certificate) to certutil:

```
certutil -verify -urlfetch path\remoteserver.cer
```

The output may be a bit complex, but it will provide additional information, which you don't get with X509Chain debugging. The most common issue (after untrusted root) is `RevocationOffline` and certutil will show revocation checking details, including each URL availability and validity.

Comment: I will certainly try using certutil and I appreciate your suggestion.  However, I want to point out that I explicitly said that I am getting this error ***before*** the ServerCertificateValidationCallback fires off, as verified by placing a breakpoint in on the return true.

Comment: I just used certutil with the certificate that I am reasonably sure is the remote server's and it passed validation. I say reasonably sure because I got the certificate via browsing to the web address and downloading the certificate through my client browser.  I have submitted a request that they send my their public certificate but I don't have high hopes for response.